# Вытащить текст из лейбла UWP приложения на Windows 10

Tags: c++, uwp, reverse-engineering

У меня есть навязчивая идея, с реализацией которой возникли проблемы. Собственно, к сабжу.
Есть приложение Яндекс.Музыки для Windows 10, приложение не win32, а UWP из Microsoft Store. С приложения играет музыка. Нужно вытащить из лейбла (или как оно там в новых UI называется) имя артиста и название играющего трека.
В приложениях win32 можно легко вытащить весь нужный текст из лейблов через хэндл окна и поиск дочерних элементов, здесь же я могу получить только хэндл окна класса ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow.
Вопрос. Может быть есть какая-нибудь библиотека C++ для работы с элементами UI в UWP? Или нужно лезть в процессы и ковыряться в памяти приложения? Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей можно использовать [UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).